# jquery same random variable in array declaration

Tags: jquery, arrays

Im using this function to generate a random string

```
function makeid(size)
    {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        for( var i=0; i < size; i++ )
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

        return text;
    }
```

I try to create an array with two times the same random value like:

```
        var game = {
            _id:makeid(24),
            createdOn:new Date(),
            id : _id
        }
```

However the error shows _id is not defined. when I remove id:_id it is valid. Why is _id not defined at this moment, the decleration is above id:_id in the same scope right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot initialize the (game.)id to be equal to (game.)_id, first off you not referencing the object you just created so it would be looking for an variable _id which doesnt exist.
Secondly, the object hasn't been instantiated yet so you can't reference that variable in the first place, you can do this though:

```
var _id = makeid(24);
var game = {
    createdOn:new Date(),
    id : _id
}
```

Comment: Basically the same answer here, with a jsFiddle for you to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/tz746xdz/

Comment: @johnny5 is it in anyway possible to access the variable in the array decleration?

Comment: @SvenB to access a variable in an object during its instanciation  is not possible that I know of. You would have to access it either after you created it, or you would have to store it in a separate variable as shown above.  Why does it have to happen during creation

Comment: @johnny5 im just trying some code, im used to programming c++ mostly but am trying some angular. I like to understand how the declerations etc work.

Comment: Okay Cool, well if anything they're simialar operation to Anonymous Types in C#,  You can directly assign variables, but cannot access that object until after instanciation